# Trouble creating method to go from pounds to kilograms

Tags: java

I am just starting `Java` so I know basically nothing about the language. I come from a `Python` background so I know this would look like this in `Python`:

```
def lbs2kg(w):
    return 0.453592*w
```

But of course it isn't that simple in Java. How would I do this in `Java`? What does `public static void main(String[] args)` mean?

Anything to send me in the right direction on how to do this simple question the `Java` way would be awesome. I tried myself and I seem to get errors pointing to missing semi colons. When do I put a semi colon?

Comment: This isn't a good way to learn a language.  Pick up a book, read a web tutorial.

Comment: You should look at a basic tutorial first.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Fair enough. Do you have any you could recommend?

Comment: You can google almost anything you want to know in `Java`. This is a good one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Good Luck! :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Much appreciated! Have a good one.

Comment: @iamtesla best of luck my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, unlike in Python, there are no straight-up functions; everything is a method in a class. The closest you can get are static methods, which are associated with the class as a whole and not any particular instance of it.

The closest you can get in Java to the Python code you posted is this:

```
public class Conversions {
    public static double lbs2kg(double w) {
        return 0.453592 * w;
    }
}
```

I would definitely recommend learning the language from a book or tutorial such as those that others have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely look into learning from a book. I'm learning at school from "JAVA: An Eventful Approach" While I don't use the book much for learning, it is invaluable as a reference guide.
Anyway, this should do the trick:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboardScan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input amount:");
        double size = keyboardScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Answer: "+ size*0.453592);
    }
```

While this works, it is useful as a runnable example with keyboard inputs. In a real program you wouldn't want the keyboard stuff. See @Taymon's post below for better form.

Comment: I wouldn't use an instance variable here. And you don't really want I/O code mixed in with a pure function.

Comment: @Taymon understandable. Thank you.